# Macros for Excel to replace text or add to the end and beginning of the cell

Tags: html, vba, excel, macros

I have tried many different options but nothing seems to work. I have different text in column M and have HTML code in column N. I need to insert text from M column to HTML code in column N. I thought about 2 options:

1st
add part of html code to the beginning and the end of the text in a cell, but when I try to add html code that includes characters like <> "" I get an error that macros or formula contain errors.

2nd
Take values from the cell M and replace text '123456789' in html code (Column N). The problem is that all values in rows (column M) are different and if I use 'find and replace' function for the row I have to do it 1000 times manually as I have 1000 rows.

If anyone could help me with macros that take values from M2,M3... and replace (row by row) '123456789' from N2,N3...HTML code or how to make macros ignore symbols <>"" as part of the code and treat it as text to insert, I would really appreciate that!

Worksheet example:

> M2 = H10xL15 / N2 = Html code that includes '123456789' to be replaced
>
> M3 = H2xL5xW12 / N3 = Html code that includes '123456789' to be replaced
>
> M4 = H15*L15 / N4 = Html code that includes '123456789' to be replaced

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: So you are looking for a VBA equivalent of the formula `REPLACE(N2,FIND("123456789",N2),9,M2)`?

Comment: If you are using quotes within a text string (which is itself demarcated by quotes), you need to double the included quote marks.  So `<>""` would be something like `"<>"""""` in a VBA text string

Comment: Can you post the picture of your data in Excel and share some of the data to the question? I think I can help you if you do that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Basically, I need to insert specifications to HTML code (instead 123....). This is picture of my sheet: http://www.ninjahunter.co.uk/urbancitygear.com/pictures/excel.png

Comment: It all worked with your provided formula, just had to 'paste values' in another cell to get rid of formula. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to – YowE3K's comment,  if you can afford to just do a formula in another cell, this would do exactly what you were wanting to do `=REPLACE(N2,FIND("123456789",N2,1),9,M2)` .  To test it, I did this:

```
Range(M2) = H10xL15
Range(N2) = <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="CodeProject Latest articles - Android" href="http://www.codeproject.com/WebServices/123456789/ArticleRSS.aspx?cat=22" />

Results:  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="CodeProject Latest articles - Android" href="http://www.codeproject.com/WebServices/H10xL15/ArticleRSS.aspx?cat=22" />
```